# Show that the optimal solution is unique

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Please, can someone help me with the (c)? I made the first two however I am struggling to get the last point. I got $\bar{x} = (4,8,5,0,0,0)$. I can't see why it should be true that for every feasible solution $x$ of value $17, \{j:x_j \not=0\} \subset B$.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that $(4,8,5,0,0,0)$ is an optimal point, let $(4+z_1,8+z_2,5+z_3,z_4,z_5,z_6)$ be another optimal point of this LP, we show that $z_i=0$ for all $i\in [6]$. Looking at the coefficients of $x_4,x_5,$ and $x_6$ in the objective function (which are all negative), and the nonnegativity of variables, we must have $z_4=z_5=z_6=0$. Because otherwise, the objective function decreases!

Next, we show that $z_1=z_2=z_3=0$. For this, by looking at the constraints, note that $(4+z_1,8+z_2,5+z_3,0,0,0)$ is only feasible iff $z_1=z_2=z_3=0$. Thus, for optimality, we have $z_i=0$ for all $i\in [6]$; concluding that $(4,8,5,0,0,0)$ is the only optimal solution.